# v-for classes rendered over each other

Tags: css, vue.js, css-grid

I've got an array of objects I want to iterate over. Each object is displayed in it's own div. In this particular list are only three objects so I could just place them manually with grid-row in css-grid, but for another page I possibly need hundreds.

Currently, the three classes are rendered on top of each other in stead of under each other.

```
    <div class="sidebar-last-three" v-for="patient in this.lastThree">
        <div class="patient-entry">
            <span class="patient-name">{{patient.value}}</span>
            <span class="patient-date">{{patient.key}}</span>
            <span class="dots">...</span>
            <span class="line"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is the css I use.

```
.sidebar-last-three{
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 7/30;
    grid-column: 1/11;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(30, 1fr);
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}
.patient-entry{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/6;
    grid-row: auto;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(15, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(15, 1fr);
}
```

[How it currently is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA8Qr.png)

[How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgo5W.png)

I guess it has something to do with using v-for to create the classes, since normally with css-grid the child divs automatically go into rows and columns. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have styling wrong. Can you supply working code like jsfiddle ?

Comment: @AdamOrlov I've tried to make one, but it doesn't seem to work..https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/494600/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styling you need:

```
.sidebar {
  display: grid;
  position: fixed;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 1 fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 1 fr);
  grid-column: 1;
  width: 16.8vw;
  height: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #26292c;
  z-index: 1; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
}
.patient-name{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
  grid-column: 3/15;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
.patient-date{
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #98acc1;
  grid-column: 3/15;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}
.line{
  background-color: #424a51;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  grid-column: 1/16;
  grid-row: 5;
}
.dots{
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  align-self: center;
  grid-column: 14/15;
  grid-row: 1/2;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.sidebar-last-three{
  display: grid;
}
.patient-entry{
  display: grid;
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: auto;
}
```

I've moved your example to codepen.

Try if this works for you.
[Here is working example:](https://codepen.io/Adam_Orlov/pen/pQMRrJ)

Comment: That's precisely what I was looking for, now I can finally move on!

Answer (score 0):

hope this might help you.

```
    <style>
.sidebar-last-three{
    display: grid;
}
.patient-entry{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: auto;
    grid-row: auto;
}
</style>

<div class="sidebar-last-three" v-for="patient in this.lastThree">
        <div class="patient-entry">
            <span class="patient-name">one on top of the one</span>
            <span class="patient-date">MM/DD/YY</span>
            <span class="dots">...</span>
            <span class="line"></span>
        </div>
            <div class="patient-entry">
            <span class="patient-name">one on top of the two</span>
            <span class="patient-date">MM/DD/YY</span>
            <span class="dots">...</span>
            <span class="line"></span>
        </div>
            <div class="patient-entry">
            <span class="patient-name">one on top of the three</span>
            <span class="patient-date">MM/DD/YY</span>
            <span class="dots">...</span>
            <span class="line"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks @vssadineni, but Im looking for something that will create the three classes using v-for, since then I can get the elemtents from that object using patient.key and so on. This one has just three, but for another page I need to make a grid of dozens.